# python script for azure activity log

Tags: python, azure

```
from azure.monitor import MonitorClient
#from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorMgmtClient
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
import datetime

# Replace this with your subscription id
subscription_id = '************'

# See above for details on creating different types of AAD credentials
credentials = UserPassCredentials(
'****',  # Your user
'****',      # Your password
)

client = MonitorClient(
  credentials,
  subscription_id
 )

monitor_mgmt_client = MonitorManagementClient(
  credentials,
  subscription_id
)
```

after running this code its giving error:
raise error
msrest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: , InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should not use `UserPassCredentials` anymore, it has been deprecated.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python#mgmt-auth-legacy):

> In previous version of the SDK, ADAL was not yet available and we provided a `UserPassCredentials` class. This is considered deprecated and should not be used anymore.

For Authenticate with token credentials, you could try the code below.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = 'ABCDEFGH-1234-1234-1234-ABCDEFGHIJKL'

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = 'a2ab11af-01aa-4759-8345-7803287dbd39'

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = 'password'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)
```

If you need more control, it is recommended to use ADAL and the SDK ADAL wrapper.

```
import adal
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AdalAuthentication
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = 'ABCDEFGH-1234-1234-1234-ABCDEFGHIJKL'

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = 'a2ab11af-01aa-4759-8345-7803287dbd39'

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = 'password'

LOGIN_ENDPOINT = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory
RESOURCE = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(LOGIN_ENDPOINT + '/' + TENANT_ID)
credentials = AdalAuthentication(
    context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials,
    RESOURCE,
    CLIENT,
    KEY
)
```

For more details, you could refer to this link : **[Authenticate with the Azure Management Libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python)**.

If you don't have an AD App, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application) to create it. To get the client id(client id is the same with application id) and key, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key).

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks a lot it was helpful.I think login is good now. But now stuck with the **activity log** fetch data to a directory.
`activity_logs = client.activity_logs.list(
    filter=filter,
    select=select
)
        

for log in activity_logs:
    # assert isinstance(log, 
          azure.monitor.models.EventData)
            print log
    `